# changing out spells gained from feats or racial abilities

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I have an elf paladin with the fey touched feat.

Palain spells are changed out/prepared as part of a long rest and the Blessed Warrior fighting style says you can swap cantrips when leveling however I can't see any wording or ruling on when or if I can swap out the spells learned from the  elf racial ability or feat, other than the ones I have at the time of character creation or upon gaining the feat.

Comment: I’ve added the [dnd-5e] tag, assuming that was what you meant by the [5.e] tag.

Comment: Can you quote the description you're reading? Because the one I can find is abundantly clear on what you can or cannot swap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Spells gained from feats and racial traits cannot be swapped out, unless a particular feature says so.

Spells gained from a particular feature can only be changed if some particular feature explicitly says they can be. There isn’t really a rule that explicitly states this, it more comes the basic principle of “features tell you how they work”. If you want to know if your racial spell can be changed, check that racial trait text to see if it can be changed. If a different feature allowed you change a racial spell, that feature would explicitly explain that.